# Resize nodes in vis js which has label inside e.g. Circle, Box

Tags: javascript, font-awesome, vis.js, vis.js-network

How to set size of shapes in vis js which can have label inside?
e.g.

Code1:

```
    shape: 'circle',
    color: {
        border: 'black',
        background: 'white'
    },
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderWidthSelected: 2,
```

in above Code1, if there is nothing in label to put in shape circle, then how i can increase/decrease the size of same.
 If shape is anything for which label is put outside we can increase and decrease the size of icons. e.g.

Code2:

```
    shape: 'icon',
    icon: {
        face: 'FontAwesome',
        code: '\uf1db',
        size: 100,
        color: '#000000'
    }
```

As in above Code2 for icon 'size' option is available.
Is there any way to use 'size' option in Code1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation states

> *"...The **size** is used to determine the size of node shapes that do not
> have the label inside of them. These shapes are: **image**, **circularImage**,
> **diamond**, **dot**, **star**, **triangle**, **triangleDown**, **square** and **icon**..."*

So the answer is **no**. *(Details can be found here https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/nodes.html)*

But as an workaround you could do something like this:

```
shape: 'circle',
scaling: {
    label: {
        enabled: true,
        min: 50,
        max: 50
    }
},
value: 1
```

Where as with the `scaling.label.min` and `scaling.label.max` property, you could, change the size of the node. *(but you will need a `value`, for the node)* I hope this helps.